# How process under android selinux context was labeled？

Tags: android, selinux

I‘m trying to do the [Android SElinux implementation](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/implement#steps), For the files, I could define file selinux security context with the flie_contexts file , Say I was adding a **/system/bin/mymodule** file, So I could sign it's scontext with add it to **/system/sepolicy/private/flie_contexts**, But what if the process's selinux security context, I can't find somewhere I could simply define them

I know the process security context was inherited by its parent process, But Is there any mechanism I could force setting process security context just like the file?

Any Insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to do:

**1. Define a Context**

Let's assume you want to create a custom context called `np_mybinary` for your binary.

This is what your `.te` file will have to contain:

```
type np_mybinary, domain;
type np_mybinary_exec, exec_type, vendor_file_type, file_type;
```

This is what your `file_contexts` file will have to contain:

```
/system/bin/mymodule  u:object_r:np_mybinary_exec:s0
```

**2. Define a Transition**

You need to define the transition from the parent process context to `np_mybinary_exec`.

```
domain_auto_trans(<parent-context>, np_mybinary, np_mybinary_exec)
```

If your process is started by init, there is a [simple macro](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/refs/heads/pie-release/public/te_macros#162) available:

```
init_daemon_domain(np_mybinary);
```